# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint vb question

Tags: vba

I have coded a vb app using to generate ppt using

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
```

But when I close my app, all power point presentations gets closed ( even the powerpoint presentation not generated by my app. )

I have closed the app at the end by

```
ppApp.Quit() // where ppApp is an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
```

I would appreicate deeply if anyone could please guide me as to how can I close and exit app without quitting all other powerpoint presentations

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start will do a ShellExecute that knows how to process a .lnk.
(Assuming you have a short cut link to Powerpoint)

```
Process.Start(shortcutPath)
```

Comment: I did Process.Start(shortCutPathToPowerPointToOpen) but after the powerpoint is populated with data when I close my application, the powerpoint that was generated as well as all other powerpoint presentations that was open closes abrubtly.